# QT Designer: Connect QSlider and QDoubleSpinBox (both ways)

Tags: qt, designer, maya, qspinbox, qslider

I'm new to QT Designer and am building interfaces for Maya. In most tutorials I've seen, setting signals/slots between two objects is pretty straightforward.

I'm trying to setup a slider and spinbox to drive each other. If the slider is updated, the value in the spinbox updates, and vice versa. However, there don't seem to be any updates for all the connections I try.

I want to try and do this purely through QT Designer.

Here's an image of the options I get going from the slider to the spinbox:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried connecting `QSlider::valueChanged` with `QDoubleSpinBox::setValue` and viceversa?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like neither widget has a 'setValue' input. I do see the 'valueChanged' though.

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791621/how-to-connect-a-qslider-to-qdoublespinbox

Comment: BTW, both QSlider and QDoubleSpinBox do have setValue

Comment: Hmm for some reason they don't show in the connection setup box.

Comment: Why are you using a QDoubleSpinBox in the first place, since QSlider uses int? As described in the link I mentioned, you should do your own slot to manage type conversion. But If you use a QSpinBox you don't need this extra step.

Comment: That's a good point. I like the float instead of int. But that doesn't seem super important when I take another look. Went and used a regular QSpinBox and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of my Maya's script use something similar, except that these are `Int` in the `QSpinBox`. I use these sliders to set the first and last frame when baking animations.

Here is a screenshot (couldn't manage to move the labels on it, sorry)[image]

If you use the signals ans slots in the table below, this should work fine.

```
_______________________________________________________________________
| Source Widget | Signal            | TO | Slot          | Dest Widget |
|---------------|-------------------|----|---------------|-------------|
| QSlider       | sliderMoved(int)  | TO | setValue(int) | QSpinBox    |
| QSpinBox      | valueChanged(int) | TO | setValue(int) | QSlider     |
```